# request.ContentType = "application/json" gives bad request error on WCF method

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest

I have created a WCF service using [WCF REST Service Template 40(CS)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd)  and method header looks like this:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "CTNotification", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]      

public string CTNotification(Stream contents)
```

and here is how I am using it:

```
 string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceUrl"];                  
 string requestUrl = string.Format("{0}CTNotification", url);

 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
 request.Method = "POST";
 request.ContentType = "application/json";
 //request.ContentType = "text/plain"; 
 request.Timeout = 5000000;                

 byte[] fileToSend = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/json.txt"));
 request.ContentLength = fileToSend.Length;

 using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
 {
     // Send the file as body request.
     requestStream.Write(fileToSend, 0, fileToSend.Length);
     requestStream.Close();
 }

 using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
     Console.WriteLine("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", response.ProtocolVersion, (int)response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription);

 Label1.Text = "file uploaded successfully";
```

It gives bad error 400. but if it make the content type plain, it works but I want to pass json which is stored in json.txt. Please suggest me how to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your service is giving 400 error because the data you are passing to the service is not in JSON format. You have decorated your operation contract with `RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` so it only accept data in JSON format.

You are making request to the service with `Stream` data and its MIME type are `"text/plain" and "application/octet-stream"`. To send JSON to the service which stored in file you need to make below changes in your service as well as client:

Service:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "CTNotification", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

public string CTNotification(string contents)
```

Client:

```
string fileToSend = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/json.txt"));
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: My requirement is to send Json as stream because when i send json as string it has double quotes around it where the clients of this service will send json without double quotes.